# Show that $\sum_{d \mid p-1} T(d) = p-1$ where $p$ is prime and $T(d) = \# \{a \mid 1 \le a \le p - 1, \, (a,\,p-1)=d \}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I'm trying to show that $$\sum_{d \mid p-1} T(d) = p-1,$$ where $p$ is prime and $T(d) = \# \{a \mid 1 \le a \le p - 1, \, (a,\,p-1)=d \}$.

I really don't even know how to begin on this problem. A hint would be appreciated.

This question is a subpart of a problem to prove that $\sum_{d \mid p-1} \varphi(d) = p-1$.

Comment: $T(n)$ is just $\varphi\left(n\right)$ when $n>1$, and $0$ when $n=1$. So what you really should prove is that $\sum_{d\mid n} \varphi\left(d\right) = n$. Hint: how many of $1, 2, \ldots, n$ have gcd $d$ with $n$ ?

Comment: @KCd Sorry, it was a typo, it's suppose to be $(a,\, p-1) = d$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Please see the edited post.

Comment: Ah! This is even simpler then. Think about what exactly you are summing.